# Prove true in natural numbers (Peano Arithmetic)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

While reviewing old exercise sheets, I have found this question and am having difficulties understanding some of the logic:

Let $\mathbb{N}$(natural numbers) be a model for Peano Arithmetic, that means $\mathbb{N}$$\vDash$PA. Choose which of the following sentences are true in $\mathbb{N}$.

**(a)** $\lnot$$\exists$x((sx=0)$\to$(0=s0)) $\to$ (($\lnot$$\exists$x(sx=s0))$\to$(0=s0))

**(b)** (($\lnot$$\exists$x(sx=s0))$\to$(0=s0)) $\to$ $\lnot$$\exists$x((sx=s0)$\to$(0=s0))

**(c)** (($\exists$x(sx=0))$\to$(0=s0)) $\to$ $\exists$x((sx=s0)$\to$(0=s0))

---

For **(a)** I would say that it is true in $\mathbb{N}$, because if you set $\color{red}{x=0}$ then you get $\lnot$$\exists$x((s$\color{red}{0}$=0)$\to$(0=s0)) which is true. Then the second part of the implication I would also set x=0 again and in the end that part ends up also being true, so we have True implies True, hence **(a)** is true in $\mathbb{N}$.

For **(b)** I would start off by letting x=0 so then I would get (($\lnot$$\exists$x(s0=s0)) , which is false, and I can see that (0=s0) is also false, so False to False, hence first part of the implication is True.

Now this is is where i have run into some confusion. My professor had solved the second part of the implication by setting $\color{red}{x=s0}$,so we then have, $\lnot$$\exists$x((s$\color{red}{s0}$=s0)$\to$(0=s0)) , and this part would be false, so all together True to False, hence **(b)** is false in $\mathbb{N}$.

I can not understand the logic behind setting x=s0 in **(b)**. Why is that allowed, when in **(a)** we didn't do that.

It would be greatly appreciated, if someone could please explain this and also provide some guidance for **(c)**.

Comment: ah yes i meant $\exists$x , thanks for pointing that out. Just made the corrections.

Comment: Are we assessing whether they are valid logical manipulations, or valid statements of arithmetic?

Comment: You said $\lnot\exists x((sx=0)\to(0=s0))$ is true, but it is false.  In fact, $(sx=0)\to(0=s0)$ is true for all $x$ and in particular it is true when $x=0$.  The reason you gave does not make sense; you cannot simply "set $x$ to $0$" inside the scope of a quantifier.

Comment: For the first, note that $\exists x((sx=0)\to ( 0=s0))$ is true. For pick $x=17$, or $0$. The $sx=0$ is false, so the implication is true. So the negated version is false, and therefore your original big sentence is true.

Comment: @MJD ok, but would it then be possible to set x to 0 inside the scope of a quantifier in this case?:  $\lnot$$\exists$((sx=s0)$\to$(0=s0)

Comment: It is never correct to set $x$ to 0 the way you did in your discussion of statement 1.

Comment: @MJD and for **(b)** , why did my professor choose to set x to s0 in the second implication, that I still can not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **(b)** :

> $[¬∃x(sx=s0) → (0=s0)] → ¬∃x[(sx=s0)→(0=s0)]$

the "strategy" of you teacher is to prove it *false* showing that the antecedent is *true* and the consequent *false*.

But the RHS conditional is negated; thus we want that both the LHS : $¬∃x(sx=s0) → (0=s0)$ and the un-negated part of the RHS : $∃x((sx=s0)→(0=s0))$ are *true*.

---

*i)* Consider the LHS; it has $0=s0$ in the consequent, and this is always *false* (it means : $1=0$).

So, we have to find a value for $x$ such that the antecedent of the LHS conditional : $¬∃x(sx=s0)$ is *false*.

But $¬∃x(sx=s0)$ is *false*, because we can find some value for $x$ such that $sx=s0$ is true... it is enough to choose $0$ as value for $x$.

Thus, it is true that "there are values for $x$ such that $sx=s0$ holds", and so the negation of this sentence, i.e. $¬∃x(sx=s0)$ is *false*.

---

*ii)* Conider now the RHS; we want that the un-negated formula : $∃x((sx=s0)→(0=s0))$ is *true*.

So, the question is : can we find a value $n$ for $x$ such that : $(sn=s0)→(0=s0)$ is *true* ?

Again, we have the false consequent : $(0=s0)$; thus, in order to "verify" the conditional, we need a value $n$ for $x$ such that $(sn=s0)$ is *false*.

Now it is enough to choose $1$ (as our $n$) as value for $x$ and we have : $2 \ne 1$, i.e. :

> $\lnot (ss0=s0)$;

this shows that "there are values for $x$ such that $sx=s0$ does not hold", i.e. $sx=s0$ is *false* for some value of $x$.

Summing up, we can find a value for $x$ such that $(sx=s0) \rightarrow (0=s0)$ is : $False \rightarrow TRUE$, i.e. $TRUE$, and so the sentence $∃x[(sx=s0) \rightarrow (0=s0)$ is *true*.

---

---

For **(c)**, taking into account that in $\mathbb N$ $(0=s0)$ is *false*, we can rewrite it as :

> $(∃x(sx=0) → FALSE) → ∃x((sx=s0) → FALSE)$.

Now, it is quite simple to find its truth value : $∃x(sx=0)$ is *false* in $\mathbb N$, because $0$ is **not** the successor of any number. Thus, we have :

> $(FALSE → FALSE) → ∃x((sx=s0) → FALSE)$, i.e.
>
> $TRUE → ∃x((sx=s0) → FALSE)$.

Now, in order to have it *true*, we need a *true* consequent, and so we have to check if we can "verify" $∃x((sx=s0) → FALSE)$. Again, the only way to "verify" it is to find a value for $x$ such that $(sx=s0) → FALSE$ is *true*, i.e.  we have to find a value for $x$ such that $(sx=s0)$ is *false*.

So, it is enough to choose $1$ and we have a value for $x$ such that $(sx=s0) → FALSE$ is *true*, i.e. $∃x((sx=s0) → FALSE)$ is *true* in $\mathbb N$, and also the complete formula is.

Comment: thank you very much for this explanation. I now have a better understanding :)